# EmberJS console error- Error while loading route: undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-rails

I am a beginner in EmberJS. It would be great if you can give a detailed explanation.
I have api end point for fetching the products which expects the GET request to the following url-

```
/api/products?date=2014-09-16&meal_type=2
```

Here, date and meal_type are the query parameters. My router.js looks like this-

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('products', { path: '/products/date/:date/meal/:mealType'} );
    });

    App.Router.reopen({
      location: 'history'
    });
```

The reason for this dynamic route is that the url of my application appears to be in the same format.

routes/product.js looks like-

```
    App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {
        return this.store.findQuery('product', {date: params.date, meal_type: params.mealType});
    },

      queryParams: {
        date: {
          refreshModel: true
        },
        mealType: {
          refreshModel: true
        }
      },
```

});

controller/products_controller.js

```
    App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      queryParams: ['date', 'meal_type'],
      date: null,
      meal_type: null,

      products: function() {
        return this.get('model.content');
      }.property()
```

I am getting an error on browser console-

```
Error while loading route: undefined
```

This appears to be in line ember.js?body=1:3522.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try this: change /// this.resource('products', { path: '/products/date/:date/meal/:mealType'} );/// to this.resource('products');. As I suspect, the path is just to specify the url, and because you are routing with that url thus having such error. Try to log the params with the code I included, if the params is visible then you can go ahead and do whatever you are doing in your route. Hope it helps.

Comment: The url including path has been set for dynamic routing. I tried your solution but got an error 
`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/products/date/2014-09-16/meal/1' did not match any routes in your application`

Comment: of course, it would return an error. If you want a route with that url. It should be something like this:

this.resource('products', function(){
 this.resource('date', 'path': '/:products_date', function(){
  this.resource('meal', 'path': '/:products_meal')
 })
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research on the error, I figured out the inconsistency in database. I resolved the error by restoring the consistent database dump.

Conclusion: EmberJS expects data to be consistent. Otherwise, it can raise errors which are difficult to debug.